# Integrating FxCop Gives an error : FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am using FxCop in FAKE but it is giving an error 
i.e.

`Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid target file must be specified.
* 1 total analysis engine exceptions.`

While all targets are successfully build.

here is my code :

```
    Target "FxCop" (fun _ ->
    !! (buildDir + "/**/*.dll")
        ++ (buildDir + "/**/*.exe")
        |> FxCop (fun p ->
            {p with
                //Override default parameters
                ReportFileName = testDir + "FXCopResults.xml";

                ToolPath = "D:/Fake/FAKE-Calculator/tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe"})
)
```

It also shows : **Project error** : No targets were selected .

Comment: The `FxCop` function in FAKE should output something to the console / TeamCity log showing the actual FxCop command line being run. Look for some green text saying "FxCop command", then on the next line you should see the actual FxCop command being executed. Could you paste that command line into your question? Also, try running that command (precisely as FAKE is printing it) by hand, and see if it gives the same error when you run it by hand as when you run it under FAKE.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the problem is that you need to specify a `RuleLibraries` option, which the FAKE documentation doesn't (yet) tell you about enough. I'll do a bit of research and write an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

The FAKE documentation doesn't make it clear enough, but apparently you need to explicitly specify one of two things:

1. Which FxCop rules you want to run, or
2. The path to an "FxCop project file" (a file with the `.FxCop` extension).

I can't tell you how to write an FxCop project file since I've never done so myself, but maybe the programmer who set up the MsBuild system you've working with already did so. If he did, then you just need to add the following parameter to your `FxCop` call in your FAKE build script:

```
ProjectFile = buildDir </> "filename.FxCop"
```

where `filename`, of course, should be replaced by a real file name.

If you don't have an `FxCop` project file, then apparently you have to explicitly specify a list of FxCop rules in the `RuleLibraries` parameter. First, you need to find out which FxCop rules are available. To do that, look in your FxCop installation directory (on my system, where I have an older version of FxCop installed, it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 1.36`, but it may be different for you) for a `Rules` folder. That folder should contain several DLLs; for example, on my system, the `Rules` folder contained:

- DesignRules.dll
- GlobalizationRules.dll
- InteroperabilityRules.dll

... and several other DLLs that I'm not going to bother typing out. Now you just make that list of filenames into an F# list:

```
RulesLibraries = ["DesignRules.dll"; "GlobalizationRules.dll"] // and so on
```

There *should* be sensible defaults for that, but currently it looks like you have to specify that list of rules by hand. So try writing your target to look something like this:

```
Target "FxCop" (fun _ ->
!! (buildDir + "/**/*.dll")
    ++ (buildDir + "/**/*.exe")
    |> FxCop (fun p ->
        {p with
            //Override default parameters
            ReportFileName = testDir + "FXCopResults.xml";
            RulesLibraries = ["DesignRules.dll"; "GlobalizationRules.dll"] // etc.
            ToolPath = "D:/Fake/FAKE-Calculator/tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe"})
)
```

Remember to separate your list items with `;` (semicolon): in F#, the `,` (comma) character is ONLY for tuples. And don't just copy my example verbatim, but actually look in your FxCop installation directory to see what rule DLLs are available, and include those. (As many, or as few, as your project actually needs).

Also, I don't know if you actually have to specify the `.dll` extension; you might be able to use `["DesignRules"; "GlobalizationRules"]` (and so on). But it's probably just as simple to use the `.dll` extension and just copy and paste from the filenames.

I haven't tested this myself, so I hope this works for you. If it doesn't, let me know.

Comment: Thank you rnumm , i tried using this , it is showing Loaded namingrules.dll...
Loaded designrules.dll... and all the dlls that I have given , but then it is showing the same error as it was showing before . i.e. `* Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid
target file must be specified.
* 1 total analysis engine exceptions.

Project : error : CA0052 : No targets were selected.
Writing report to D:\Project\api\test\FXCopResults.xml...`

Comment: @johnfernandes - Could you paste the actual FxCop command being run into your question, as I requested earlier? I want to see the actual command-line options it's getting, so I can figure out why it can't find project files. Without seeing that, I don't think I'll be able to figure this out.

Comment: I figured out the problem , actually  no dlls were created in buildDir and the build folder was empty , now I will figure out why it is happening , but yes I tried this by giving another path of existing dlls , then It is working and result file is also created by FxCop . Thank You for the help :)